# Create an array of objects, having an array of data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

this time I come to you for the following, I want to create an object in JS with data that comes to me from an array, the array contains the following data:

```
const columnsTable = [
  "id",
  "name",
  "age"
];
```

Really the problem is that when this happens in vuejs it returns me as follows and it is exactly the same code, any idea?
[what is selected is the return of my computed method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBjag.png)
My computed method is as follows:
[method computed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7AwT.png)
My computer method has the same native js code and it returns me differently.
Would it be good to open another question with this topic?

The array of objects that I want to create with the above array must have the following structure:

```
 columns: [
        {
          name: 'id', align: 'center', label: 'id', field: 'id'
        },
        {
          name: 'name', align: 'center', label: 'name', field: 'name'
        },
        {
          name: 'age', align: 'center', label: 'age', field: 'age'
        }
      ]
    }
```

Where each object represented in the object array has a value from the columsTable array in name, label and field.

I am trying as follows but I am not successful:

```js
var columnsTable = [
  "id",
  "nombre",
  "edad",
];

var colums = [];

columnsTable.forEach((column) => {
  colums.push({
    name: column,
    align: 'center',
    label: column,
    field: column
  });
  console.log(colums);
});
```

Since this at the end returns all the values of my array within a property of my object. From now on I thank you, any contribution would be very helpful.

Comment: Remove the `this.` from `this.columns`?

Comment: What isn't working with your current approach?

Comment: Use [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @SimoneRossaini ***The snippet you make is wrong!!!*** OP clearly states there is an object, so the snippet is ***misleading*** to what that code does  - `this` will be the equal to `window` there, [instead of an object](https://jsbin.com/viqiver/1/edit?js,console) which drastically change the semantics of the code.

Comment: So what is the desired return? An array of matched values or an array of objects that have matching values?

Comment: This was a syntax error and it is corrected, I will actually apply it to vuejs but I have left it in js to be clearer.

Comment: The code comes from whoever asks the question, the snippet is fair being that the code can work in the snippet. At the most, it is pointed out to him directly to the person asking the question and his code is not changed in the question. Rather answer the question instead of edit.

Comment: an array of objects that have matching values @zer00ne

Comment: @SimoneRossaini "*the snippet is fair*"  it isn't and I showed you why. By re-contextualising the snippet, you've changed its meaning. If you want clarification or feel there is no enough information, you should vote for that, not change the code to something it is not.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't change any code, I just used that of the author of the question. just look at the revision of the post, the code is same, is wrong? Yes, we can edit the wrong code into question? i think no, provide an answer instead.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini "*I didn't change any code*" you changed the context of it. Check the JSBin and see *the same code* producing different result. You have invented meaning that wasn't there.

Comment: @VLAZ [image of the original post](https://ibb.co/X3rCKKk), i just entered **his** code into the snippet....

Comment: @SimoneRossaini and I'm saying it was wrong. ***YET AGAIN*** check the example showing how ***the same code*** behaves ***differently***. Therefore, your edit wasn't representative.

Comment: @VLAZ I understood the problem but precisely because he is wrong in principle **DO NOT** correct the code in the question but **ANSWER** them by pointing out the difference, **otherwise one does not understand.**

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I've not changed the code in the question at all. *You* have changed what the code means when making it a snippet. I just removed it *because it was misleading*. And I'm not going to answer somebody's made up misleading example if it doesn't correspond to the problem the question asker has. Nor is it really clear what the problem in the question is. Something doesn't work, it may or may not be related to `this` - who knows. There is some code that works but apparently has an unknown problem. I notice you've not answered - is it because I'm right and the question is unclear?

Comment: friends, I was the one who edited the question, this is not the problem, I put this function in context, I want to pass it to vuejs and when I do that, being the same approach, this returns me differently, I will update the question with the image of what it returns and I do not understand why this happens.